# Proving that if $f(x)$ is convex then it is convex on all lines, stuck on details

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is convex, then we want to show that $f(x+tv), t\in \mathbb{R}, v  \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

To do this we can use the second derivative test:

(1) $\dfrac{d f(x+tv)}{dt} = f'(x+tv) v = \nabla f(x+tv)^T v$ (where we used $f'(x) = \nabla f(x)^T$)

(2) $\dfrac{d^2f(x+tv)}{dt^2} = (\nabla^2 f(x+tv)v)^Tv =v^T\nabla^2 f(x+tv)v  $

It doesn't seem intuitive or obvious to me as to how the proof went from (1) to (2)

Can someone show me why is that $\dfrac{d\nabla f(x+tv)^T v}{dt} = (\nabla^2 f(x+tv)v)^Tv $

More specifically, how can we see that

$\dfrac{d\nabla f(x+t)}{dt} = \nabla^2 f(x+t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. For convenience I'll denote by $DF$ the total derivative or the Jacobian of $F$ (which in your question you denoted by "$F'$" which is just not convenient, but I'll try to include your notation as well). From your notation I assume that the gradient $\nabla$ is a column vector and $\nabla^2$ is the Hessian.

1. **Prerequisites**: You need to consider $C^2$-functions to use any derivative tests. So I'll assume that's the case.
2. **The specific case**: Note that you are differentiating w.r.t. $t$, so (after pushing the transpose out of the differential by "$\frac{d}{dt}(...^T)=(\frac{d}{dt} ...)^T$ to avoid confusion) careful use of chain rule yields
   $$\frac{d}{dt} (\nabla f(x+t)^T)=(\underbrace{(D(\nabla f))}_{=(\nabla f)'=\nabla^2f^T}\kern{-0.5em}(x+t)~\frac{d}{dt}(x+t))^T=(\nabla^2 f(x+t)^T~\mathbf{1})^T =~\mathbf{1}^T~\nabla^2f(x+t)$$
   where $\mathbf{1}$ is the unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The first equality under the brace is just your notation for the total derivative of $f$. The second one can be derived from what you already used in your question in (1) ("where we used [...]" with $\nabla f$ instead of $f$) or from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Vector-valued_functions) ("The Hessian matrix can be considered related to the Jacobian matrix by [...]" with $\nabla^2$ instead of $H$).
3. **The application**: Using the same principle  yields for fixed $x,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
   $$\begin{align}\dfrac{d\nabla f(x+tv)^T v}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\nabla f(x+tv)\right)^Tv\\
   &=\big(\underbrace{(D(\nabla f))}_{=\nabla^2f^T~\text{as above}}\kern{-0.6em}(x+tv)~ \underbrace{\frac{d}{dt}(x+tv)}_{=v}\big)^T v\\
   &=(\nabla^2 f(x+tv)v)^Tv\end{align}$$
4. **Conclusion**: Suppose $f$ is convex. This is equivalent to the Hessian $\nabla^2f$ being positive definite which means
   $$\frac{d^2 f(x+tv)}{dt^2}=v^T\nabla^2f(x+tv)v\geq 0.$$
   This means that $f$ is convex along the line $\{x+tv\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$.

(I tidied up and tried to adapt more to your notation. If something's unclear or if you feel I misunderstood parts of your question, please feel free to point that out!)

Comment: Why is that $\frac{d \nabla f}{dt} = \nabla^2f$?

Comment: For the same reason as in "where we used $f'(x) = \nabla f(x)^T$". (There's a "$^T$" missing in your last sentence of the question as well as in the first part of my answer. I'm trying to edit it in correctly, but please bear with me, I'm not used to using the transpose in that way.)